# popstate keeps using last state

Tags: browser-history, html5-history, popstate

I got a simple code when users are filtering brands, categories etc..
Everything works as it should.

BUT when you for example want to go back twice, the first popstate returns the last page perfectly. But when you go back again, it still returns the last page, so it loads it again. And not the page before that one.

A piece of my code:

#### The pushstate

```
var params = $('fme_layered_params').value.parseQuery();
// Object { cat="274",  dir="desc"}

if (!params['dir'])
{
    $('fme_layered_params').value += '&dir=' + 'desc';
}
if(window.location.href.indexOf('?') > -1){
    var u = window.location.href.split("?");
    var url = u[0]+"?"+$('fme_layered_params').value;
}else
    var url = window.location.href+"?"+$('fme_layered_params').value;

window.history.pushState($('fme_layered_params').value, 'link', url);
```

#### The popstate

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) {

    if(e.state!==null){
        var state = e.state;
        state = state.split("&");
        // ["cat=272", "dir=desc"]

        jQuery.each(state, function(i,v){
            var info = v.split('=');
            fme_layered_add_params(info[0], info[1], 1);
        });
        fme_layered_make_request();
    }
};
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the propose of `if(e.state!==null)` in `onpopstate` event function handler?

Comment: Safari has the urge to call onpopstate when the page is fully loaded.
So, to prevent that i check if the state has been defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem.
Every time i went back it also pushed the current page. So i went back and the same page was pushed in history resulting in endless reloading of that certain page.

**TL;DR**?
check, double check, triple check how your code 'walks' through the lines.